# how to refer a table

Tags: tables, cross-referencing

I am using a template given by the department,
the tables I create as of now was only in chapter 2 which used to come as  `\label{tab:my_label}` generates a label Table 2.1 for first table of chapter 2.

[image: table 2.1]

But now in chapter 3 I create another table.
Here is how my relevant section of code.

```
appear below the table (See Table \ref{Table 1}).
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\vspace{1ex}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline
    {\bf Technique} & {\bf Category} \\\hline
    Supervised anomaly detection &   A\\
    \hline
    Semi Supervised Anomaly Detection & B \\ \hline
    Unsupervised anomaly detection & C\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{tab:my_label}Type of anomaly detection techniques.}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

but now in the above code I do not know how to refer to table in chapter 3. The above code is in chapter 3 for the table 3.1 .

[image: table 3.1]

The name table 3.1 is automatically generated with `\label{tab:my_label}`.
But I am not able to understand how do I refer to this table within the chapter or even outside the chapter.
The full template with which I am working can be seen [here.](https://github.com/kiotie32/original-template)

Comment: Use a speaking name in the label, e.g. `\label{tab:anomaly-detection}`, and then `\ref{tab:anomaly-detection}`. Btw: the number in the table is not created by the \label command, but by the \caption.

Comment: oh I  did not knew this it was so simple. Do we need to do same for referencing images in the document.

Comment: You can label almost everything (if is has a counter). Put e.g. \label{sec:something} behind a section command and then look what \ref{sec:something} gives. figures works too, as soon as the \label is in or behind the \caption.

Comment: There are also \pageref. Try` see table `\ref{...}` in  page  `\pageref{...}`.

Answer (score 2):

There are no problems in your example, as long as you use different labels (that is, the argument of `\label{}` for every figure/table of floating element that you have.
Just remember to always put `\label` after `\caption` (it is the latter that creates the number, as Ulrike already said).

Also, prefer `\centering` instead of `\begin{center} ... \end{center}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tb]
    \centering
    \caption{Type of anomaly detection techniques.}
    \label{tab:my_label}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline
        {\bf Technique} & {\bf Category} \\\hline
        Supervised anomaly detection &   A\\
        \hline
        Semi Supervised Anomaly Detection & B \\ \hline
        Unsupervised anomaly detection & C\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
Here is a reference \ref{tab:my_label} and a page reference \pageref{tab:my_label}.
\end{document}
```

I can also suggest the use of the [`cleveref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref?lang=en) package ;)

[image]

Comment: Instead `{\bf Technique}` in LaTeX is more correct to use `\textbf{Technique}}` or if you more prefer `{\bfseries Techniques}` :-)

Comment: thanks for pointing that out!